# Scraping HTML Data from a table (without ID) in Rails With Nokogiri without

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

I'm new to rails scraping with Nokogiri. I have a website that I need to scrape a table from: http://fantasy.premierleague.com/stats/elements/?page=1, and looks like this:

```
<table class="ismTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th>Player</th>
            <th>Team</th>
            <th><abbr title="Position">Pos</abbr></th>
            <th><abbr title="Teams selected by %">Selected</abbr></th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th><abbr title="Gameweek points">GW</abbr></th>
            <th><abbr title="Total points">Total</abbr></th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <tr>
            <td><img src="http://cdn.ismfg.net/static/plfpl/img/shirts/data_view/shirt_7.png" alt="Leicester" title="Leicester" class="ismShirtData"></td>
            <td><a href="#163" class="ismInfo ismViewProfile"><img src="http://cdn.ismfg.net/static/plfpl/img/icons/info.png" alt="Player information " width="16" height="16"></a></td>
            <td>Mahrez</td>
            <td>LEI</td>
            <td>MID</td>
            <td>61.3%</td>
            <td>£6.8</td>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>119</td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The relevant table starts with "table class="ismTable", but doesn't have an ID. This is what I currently have:

```
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://fantasy.premierleague.com/stats/elements/?page=1"))
rows = page.css('tr').map do |row|
  row.xpath('./td')
end
```

My goal is to get the information from the table, and input it into the database table for "players", which has fields below:

```
create_table "players", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "total_points"
    t.string   "team"
    t.text     "image_link"
    t.integer  "gw_points"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

So in the example HTML above, I need to create a new player entry with:
name -> Mahrez, team -> LEI, gw_points -> 21, total_points -> 119

I know I need some sort of loop, but I'm struggling to figure out how to access the table, since it doesn't have an ID.

Comment: You need to supply a minimal example of the HTML you're parsing in the question itself. Don't expect people to go to a site and sift through a page to find the relevant information. See "[ask]". The more work you do up front to help us answer you, the more answers you'll get. Accessing nodes in tables is covered many times in questions and answers here on SO.

Comment: The HTML added is a little helpful, but it's not valid. Please reduce it to the *minimum* necessary, and make sure it's valid. Anything beyond the minimum only slows people as they try to make sense of it and invalid HTML will be fixed by Nokogiri resulting in markup that is not what you gave us.

Comment: Makes sense, again sorry I'm relatively new to posting to SO. Thanks for the help.

I did in fact look at other questions, but all of them involved using some sort of ID in the Nokogiri .css or .xpath functions